# comparing strings in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, cell

I have a large string (already sorted) comprised of cells like

```
batch = [{'a'},{'a'},{'a'},{'m'},{'m'},{'q'},{'q'},{'q'},{'q'}]
```

and within a for loop, I need the indices in `batch` where say `val = {'a'}` appears, i.e., I am iterating over the distinct strings in batch--`{'a'}, {'m'}, {'q'}` in this case.

Using some fcn like `ismember` or `strcmp` or simple `find` clearly works, e.g., `find(ismember(batch, val))`
However, this is too slow for my purposes. Is it possible to find the start and last indices where `val` appears in `batch` outside of the for loop and then I can just call these indices within the for loop? Thank you.

Comment: `[{'a'},{'a'},{'a'},{'m'},{'m'},{'q'},{'q'},{'q'},{'q'}]` is the same as `{'a','a','a','m','m','q','q','q','q'}` but a lot more tedious and verbose.

Answer (score 2):

We can do a little timing experiment:

```
batch = [{'a'},{'a'},{'a'},{'m'},{'m'},{'q'},{'q'},{'q'},{'q'}];
val = {'a'}
% make the array to be searched in longer for relevant timing
Str = repmat(batch,1,1000000);
% ismember
tic
idx = find(ismember(Str,val));
toc
% strcmp
tic
idx = find(strcmp(Str,val));
toc
% contains
tic
idx = find(contains(Str,val));
toc
% cellfun/isequal
tic
idx = find(cellfun(@(x)isequal(x,val),Str));
toc
% looping
tic
idx = NaN(round(length(Str)/4),1);
k = 1;
for i = 1:length(Str)
    lg = Str{i} == val{1};
    if lg
        idx(k) = i;
        k = k+1;
    end
end
idx = idx(1:k-1);
toc
```

resulting on my machine in

- Elapsed time is 0.266673 seconds. % ismember
- Elapsed time is 0.225149 seconds. % strcmp
- Elapsed time is 0.144104 seconds. % contains
- Elapsed time is 50.683212 seconds. % cellfun + isequal
- Elapsed time is 1.689111 seconds. % loopint + isequal

It even gets worse if you use a sting-array instead of a cell array.

However, I cannot imagine that those functions are too slow for you. But I can imagine that reason why you want to do this is not optimal... so share a bit more information & code to speed-up the entire problem instead of just this subproblem (but open a new question for this;) )

Comment: An answer with timing is always nice! (+1). But you could do better with the loop, considering the input strings are sorted. A binary search, for example. Would be more complex code, but might be significantly faster for large data.